# jq - return array value if its length is not null

Tags: json, bash, jq, cicd

I have a report.json generated by a gitlab pipeline.
It looks like:

```
{"version":"14.0.4","vulnerabilities":[{"id":"64e69d1185ecc48a1943141dcb6dbd628548e725f7cef70d57403c412321aaa0","category":"secret_detection"....and so on
```

If no vulnerabilities found, then "vulnerabilities":[]. I'm trying to come up with a bash script that would check if vulnerabilities length is null or not. If not, print the value of the vulnerabilities key. Sadly, I'm very far from scripting genius, so it's been a struggle.
While searching web for a solution to this, I've come across jq. It seems like select() should do the job.
I've tried:

```
jq "select(.vulnerabilities!= null)" report.json
```

but it returned `{"version":"14.0.4","vulnerabilities":[{"id":"64e69d1185ecc48a194314...` instead of expected `"vulnerabilities":[{"id":"64e69d1185ecc48a194314...`
and

```
map(select(.vulnerabilities != null)) report.json
```

returns "No matches found"

Would you mind pointing out what's wrong apart from my 0 experience with bash and JSON parsing? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like instead of a null check, you want to check to see if the array has a length of 0 and if not, output its elements.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please note that in the JSON world, it is important to distinguish
between `[]` (the empty array), the values `0` and `null`, and the absence of a value (e.g. as the result of the absence of a key in an object).

In the following, I'll assume that the output should be the value of .vulnerabilities
if it is not `[]', or nothing otherwise:

```
< sample.json jq '
  select(.vulnerabilities != []).vulnerabilities
'
```

---

If the goal were to differentiate between two cases based on the return code from jq, you could use the -e command-line option.

Comment: I've been trying to make it return the value of vulnerabilities if the vulnerabilities are not []

Comment: @Laurian - Please see revised answer.

Comment: I was able: https://jqplay.org/s/5wiwhtRVWNh

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.` filter to identify the object `vulnerabilities`.

these is some cases below

```sh
$ jq '.vulnerabilities' <<END
heredoc> {"version":"14.0.4","vulnerabilities":[{"id":"64e69d1185ecc48a1943141dcb6dbd628548e725f7cef70d57403c412321aaa0","category":"secret_detection"}]}
heredoc> END
[
  {
    "id": "64e69d1185ecc48a1943141dcb6dbd628548e725f7cef70d57403c412321aaa0",
    "category": "secret_detection"
  }
]
```

if `vulnerabilities` null, then jq will return null

```sh
$ jq '.vulnerabilities' <<END
{"version":"14.0.4","vulnerabilities":null}
END
null
```

then with pipe `|`, you can change it to any output you wanted.

- change null to []: `.vulnerabilities | if . == null then [] else . end`
- filter empty array: `.vulnerabilities | select(length > 0)`

For further information about jq filters, you can read the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming, by "print the value of the vulnerabilities key" you mean the value of an item's `id` field. You can retrieve it using `.id` and have it extracted to bash with the `-r` option.
- If in case the array is not empty you want *all* of the "keys", iterate over  the array using `.[]`. If you just wanted a specific key, let's say the first, address it using a 0-based index: `.[0]`.
- To check the length of an array there is a dedicated `length` builtin. However, as your final goal is to extract, you can also attempt to do so right anyway, suppress a potential unreachability error using the `?` operator, and have your bash script read an appropriate exit status using the `-e` option.

Your bash script then could include the following snippet

```sh
if key=$(jq -re '.vulnerabilities[0].id?' report.json)
then
  # If the array was not empty, $key contains the first key
  echo "There is a vulnerability in key $key."
fi

# or

if keys=$(jq -re '.vulnerabilities[].id?' report.json)
then
  # If the array was not empty, $keys contains all the keys
  for k in $keys
  do echo "There is a vulnerability in key $k."
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if-then-else`.

Filter

```
if (.vulnerabilities | length) > 0 then {vulnerabilities} else empty end
```

Input

```
{
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "111",
      "category": "secret_detection"
    },
    {
      "id": "112",
      "category": "secret_detection"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "121",
      "category": "secret_detection 2"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "version": "3.1.1",
  "vulnerabilities": []
}
{
  "version": "4.1.1",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "411",
      "category": "secret_detection 4"
    },
    {
      "id": "412",
      "category": "secret_detection"
    },
    {
      "id": "413",
      "category": "secret_detection"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output

```
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "111",
      "category": "secret_detection"
    },
    {
      "id": "112",
      "category": "secret_detection"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "121",
      "category": "secret_detection 2"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "411",
      "category": "secret_detection 4"
    },
    {
      "id": "412",
      "category": "secret_detection"
    },
    {
      "id": "413",
      "category": "secret_detection"
    }
  ]
}
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/wicmr4uVRm