# Check if a key exists and return another key

Tags: json, gitlab, gitlab-ci, jq

I need help with jq syntax on how to return the Gitlab job ID if it contains an artifact. The JSON output looks like this (removed a lot of unrelated info from it and added `[...]`):

```
[{
    "id": 3219589880,
    "status": "success",
    "stage": "test",
    "name": "job_with_no_artifact",
    "ref": "main",
    "tag": false,
    "coverage": null,
    "allow_failure": false,
    "created_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:25.119Z",
    "started_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:25.986Z",
    "finished_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:38.464Z",
    "duration": 12.478682,
    "queued_duration": 0.499786,
    "user": {
        "id": 123456789,
        [...]
    },
    "commit": {
        "id": "5e0e1f287d20daf2036a3ca71c656dce55999265",
        [...]
    "pipeline": {
        "id": 123456789,
        [...]
    "project": {
        "ci_job_token_scope_enabled": false
    },
    "artifacts": [],
    "runner": {
        "id": 12270859,
        [...]
    },
    "artifacts_expire_at": null,
    "tag_list": []
}, {
    "id": 3219589878,
    "status": "success",
    "stage": "test",
    "name": "create_artifact_job_2",
    "ref": "main",
    "tag": false,
    "coverage": null,
    "allow_failure": false,
    "created_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:25.111Z",
    "started_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:25.922Z",
    "finished_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:39.090Z",
    "duration": 13.168405,
    "queued_duration": 0.464364,
    "user": {
        "id": 123456789,
        [...]
    },
    "commit": {
        "id": "5e0e1f287d20daf2036a3ca71c656dce55999265",
        [...]
    },
    "pipeline": {
        "id": 675641982,
        [...],
    "project": {
        "ci_job_token_scope_enabled": false
    },
    "artifacts_file": {
        "filename": "artifacts.zip",
        "size": 223
    },
    "artifacts": [{
        "file_type": "archive",
        "size": 223,
        "filename": "artifacts.zip",
        "file_format": "zip"
    }, {
        "file_type": "metadata",
        "size": 153,
        "filename": "metadata.gz",
        "file_format": "gzip"
    }],
    "runner": {
        "id": 12270845,
        [...]
    },
    "artifacts_expire_at": "2022-10-25T18:21:35.859Z",
    "tag_list": []
}, {
    "id": 3219589876,
    "status": "success",
    "stage": "test",
    "name": "create_artifact_job_1",
    "ref": "main",
    "tag": false,
    "coverage": null,
    "allow_failure": false,
    "created_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:25.103Z",
    "started_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:25.503Z",
    "finished_at": "2022-10-24T18:21:41.407Z",
    "duration": 15.904028,
    "queued_duration": 0.098837,
    "user": {
        "id": 123456789,
        [...]
    },
    "commit": {
        "id": "5e0e1f287d20daf2036a3ca71c656dce55999265",
        [...]
    },
    "pipeline": {
        "id": 123456789,
        [...]
    },
    "web_url": "WEB_URL",
    "project": {
        "ci_job_token_scope_enabled": false
    },
    "artifacts_file": {
        "filename": "artifacts.zip",
        "size": 217
    },
    "artifacts": [{
        "file_type": "archive",
        "size": 217,
        "filename": "artifacts.zip",
        "file_format": "zip"
    }, {
        "file_type": "metadata",
        "size": 152,
        "filename": "metadata.gz",
        "file_format": "gzip"
    }],
    "runner": {
        "id": 12270857,
    },
    "artifacts_expire_at": "2022-10-25T18:21:37.808Z",
    "tag_list": []
}]
```

I've been trying to do either of the following using jQ:

Either:

- Check if `artifacts_file` key exists in each iteration and if it does return the (job) id (so `.[].id`)
- Check if `artifacts` array is empty in each iteration and if it is empty return the (job) id.

In both cases I'm able to do the first part but I am not sure how to return the `.id` key.

Related stackoverflow questions that I've been trying to utilize and adapt to my case:

- [jq - return array value if its length is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71476198/jq-return-array-value-if-its-length-is-not-null)
- [How to check for presence of 'key' in jq before iterating over the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097410/how-to-check-for-presence-of-key-in-jq-before-iterating-over-the-values)

What I have so far: `jq '[.[].artifacts[]|select(length > 0)] | .[]'` which returns all the artifacts found (but it doesn't contain the `.id` of the job).

Comment: I could do this via shell/bash script but I think it'd be cleaner if done with jQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the existence of a field using `has`:

```bash
.[] | select(has("artifacts_file")).id
```

```
3219589878
3219589876
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dDSGNUuL4w9)

Checking if a field is an empty array by comparing it to `[]`:

```bash
.[] | select(.artifacts == []).id
```

```
3219589880
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/gI9q9Em3CIp)

Comment: Nice, I just also was able to do it this way:

`.[]| select(.artifacts_file != null) | .id`  (you beat me to the answer haha)

Comment: If you don't mind, how would you output this in a way that can be parsed easier (@tsv perhaps?).

Comment: @Fadi Checking with `.artifacts_file != null` would disregard cases with field `.artifacts_file` present but explicitly set to `null` (which might suffice for your use case, just wanted to point it out as you were asking if a "key exists").

Comment: @Fadi To use `@tsv`, which requires an array as input, don't decompose the top-level array with `.[] | …`. Rather use a `map(…)` to retain it, then apply `@tsv` to it at the end, i.e. `map(select(…).id) | @tsv` (along with the `--raw-output` or `-r` flag, of course, to output raw text).

Comment: I did `jq --raw-output '.[] | map(select(has("artifacts_file")).id) | @tsv'` but I get the following error:

`jq: error (at <stdin>:283): Cannot check whether number has a string key exit status 5`

Comment: @Fadi `map` should **replace** `.[]`, not be composed to it. See a [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1L4pKpVKaw1).